# Delphi 5 Strange result when sum double variables

Tags: delphi, floating-point, delphi-5

In Delphi 5 i have Strange problem when sum two values ​​of type double and one positive and the other negative same values .

for Example

**dbv = 50071763.721

crv = -50071763.721**

the result should **0** when sum two values but i got result some thing like  **0.0000000074505805969**

i did the sum in excel i got 0 result .

Comment: This is the world's most frequent programming question.

Comment: (It's a bit fun you needed Excel to realise that, mathematically, x + (-x) equals zero...)

Comment: What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: welcome to the world of floating point representation.

Comment: I wonder if in different countries' schools mathematics classes cover concepts of simple fractions (aka rational numbers), repeating decimals and their conversion via geometric progression, and mutually prime numbers ?  PS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon - this link was not put here yet

Comment: You are dealing with floating point numbers (surely you *must* have dealt with rounding), and your result is **almost** zero and the concept of rounding errors does not come up????

Comment: This topic tends to come back again like bad habit.  IEEE 754 values are ***approximate***.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to know what you're doing if you have even a single line of code in your question.

Comment: @FreeConsulting "IEEE 754 values are approximate." The values are exact. The results of computations are approximate.

Answer (score 7):

What you are claiming is false. For an IEEE754 compliant unit, which is what performs the calculation,

```
x + (-x) = 0
```

for all x other than NaN and Inf.

You have two values, both of which are not equal to the values in the question. We can be sure of that since neither value is representable as binary floating point values. So, clearly you have rounded to three decimal places for presentation, but the underlying numbers are not what appear in the question. And clearly your two values have different absolute value.

Required reading on this topic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: +1 for making that observation!! I didn't think of that. (Although this 'detail' probably isn't the most important thing for the OP to learn.)

Comment: Rudy makes a good summary of floats as well: [`Floating point numbers`](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
program TestXPlusMinusX;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var dbv, crv : double;

begin
  dbv := 50071763.721;
  crv := -50071763.721;
  if (dbv + crv) = 0 then WriteLn('Sum is Zero');
  WriteLn(dbv + crv);
end.
```

This gives zero, as David noted.  Since you haven't shown us your actual code, we can say nothing other than what you have told us is not what you have done.

Comment: Always test equals zero with =0 in case you fall foul of presentation rounding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Fair point - added the line.  Result is actually `0.00000000000000E+0000` which falsifies OP's claim but doesn't, I agree, necessarily prove the result is exactly zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try to round the result
for example

```
uses Math;

function fnSumValue(): Double;
var
  dbv: Double;
  crv: Double;
begin
  dbv := 50071763.721;
  crv := -50071763.721;
  Result := Math.RoundTo(Abs(dbv) - Abs(crv), -6);
end;
```

Comment: Why? `dbv + crv` is exactly equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how floating point numbers are represented.

Your best chance is to define a precision you need, let's say 0.001.

Multiply dbv and crv by 1000 (1/1000=0.001) and round to integer. Now do your sum. Divide back by 1000. Here's your result with needed precision.

```
result := (round(dbv*1000)+round(crv*1000))/1000;
```

Comment: This will not generally fix the problem. Suppose, for example, one of the numbers is 1.1110… and the other is 1.1114999…. Both would appear, when displayed with three decimal places, as “1.111”. When the former is multiplied by 1000, the result is 1111.0…, and rounding it to an integer produces 1111, which is fine. But, when the latter is multiplied by 1000, the result might be 1111.5 due to rounding, and then rounding to an integer will produce 1112. Then dividing these by 1000 will produce different numbers.